# Java Getting remote machine time

Tags: java, time

I am creating a login/authentication program for employees in a company using Java. The database is on a remote machine from the program. When a user logs in, I must save the time of the login. I would like to get the time from the remote machine. This ensures an authoritative timestamp

The remote machine runs windows2000 server. How can I get the remote time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide much more information. Are you accessing the database directly or some kind of api ??

Answer (score 0):

[NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) is the ODBC canonical function for this. The link is to the MySQL version; your database's implementation may vary.